# Copy nested struct from memory to storage

Tags: solidity, contract-development, struct

I have a fully filled struct ( in memory ), I want to store it ( in storage ), but I can't convert it.
I've tested many ways and I got two kinds of errors:

- copying of type struct of Player memory[] memory to storage not yet supported
- explicit conversion error

  ```
    mapping(uint256 => Match) public matchList;

    struct Team {
    Player[] players;
    }

    struct Player {
    address username;
    uint256 index;
    uint256 payableInUSD;
    }

    struct MatchOption {
    uint256 entry;
    uint256 date;
    uint256 createAt;
    uint256 matchId;
    }

    struct Match {
    MatchOption matchOption;
    Team[] teams;
    uint256 price;
    uint256 createAt;
    }

   specificMatch   // this is a Match(struct) in memory, I have it fully 
   filled from frontend

    Match[] storage copiedMatch= specificMatch;  // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    matchList[0] = copiedMatch;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't explicitly fill your new `specificMatch` array in deployment of the code. Rather, you would have to create a function to fill the new array with the structs you wish to store in it. As a state variable, these would automatically then be stored in storage.