# Copying memory[] to storage not supported on initialization

Tags: solidity, storage, struct, memory

I have a data structure where:

1. The smart contract holds an array of structs (a "community") in state
2. That struct has an array of structs ("delegates")

When I try initialize one of the top level structs (a "community") and push it to the array, I get the error:

> UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct contributor memory[]
> memory to storage not yet supported.

Code to reproduce this is here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.23;

struct contributor {
    address id;
    string description;
    bool community;
}

struct community {
    address id;
    string description;
    contributor[] delegates;
}

contract communityDelegator {
     community[] public communities;

      // Make a constructor
      constructor() public {
      }

     // Function to add a new community
     function createCommunity(string calldata newDescription) public {

      community memory newCommunity = community({
         id: msg.sender,
         description: newDescription,
         delegates:  new contributor[](0) // Getting rid of this and changing the community type signature works
      });

      communities.push(newCommunity);

     }

}
```

I get that if I have a struct in memory, to copy to storage I'd have to loop over every element ([example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/140151/copy-nested-struct-from-memory-to-storage)). But there's nothing to loop over because I'm just trying to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the `UnimplementedFeatureError` in Solidity, first, create an empty array of contributors in memory. Then, initialize the struct's delegates array with this empty array inside the function. By doing this, you avoid directly assigning an empty memory array to a storage array, allowing successful struct initialization and array population. Finally, push the initialized struct into the storage array.

Code Snippet:

```
Contributor[] memory emptyContributors;
Community memory newCommunity = Community({
    id: msg.sender,
    description: newDescription,
    delegates: emptyContributors
});
communities.push(newCommunity);
```